# How to restrict certain rows in a Django model to a department?

Tags: django, django-admin

This looks like it should be easy but I just can't find it.

I'm creating an application where I want to give admin site access to people from different departments. Those people will read and write the same tables, BUT they must *only access rows belonging to their department!* I.e. they must not see any records produced by the other departments and should be able to modify only the records from their own department. If they create a record, it should automatically "belong" to the department of the user which created it (they will create records only from the admin site).

I've found django-guardian, but it looks like an overkill - I don't really want to have arbitrary per-record permissions.

Also, the number of records will potentially be large, so any kind of front-end permission checking on a per-record basis is not suitable - it must be done by DB-side filtering. Other than that, I'm not really particular how it will be done. E.g. I'm perfectly fine with mapping departments to auth groups.

Comment: For reads, do something like TheModel.objects.filter(user__in=the_list_of_the_users_in_dept). For writes, you can create a custom save method which automatically inserts the user department. It is however difficult to be more precise without seeing your code.

Comment: There is no working code, I'm in the process of creating it. But let's go with your suggestion: where would I put the filter code so that it is enforced both in the admin interface and in the app code?